# Android stopped informing me about app permissions. Why?

Tags: permissions

Since I upgraded to Marshmallow (Verizon LG-G4), I never get the little dialog that asks me to approve new permissions for applications I'm installing/updating, nor even the "no new permissions needed" notice.

Is this a Marshmallow issue? Did I accidentally do something to turn those off? If so, how do I turn them back on? I can't find any settings that govern this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marshmallow comes with a new feature that asks for app permissions when opening the app. It has the new apple-esque asking for permissions feature. You can choose if an app can use these permissions or not.

If you want to change the permissions later, go to settings and search "Permissions"

If the app requires no permissions, it will not inform you of that. 
However, if it requested access to something, it will tell you.
For example, if I just installed Skype and started using the microphone, it will ask if the app can use the microphone. You can decline it or accept it.
 [image]

Comment: When I downloaded SpanishDict it didn't mention permissions on download or on opening.

Comment: @Robusto Hmm, that's funny. Maybe LG took it out or its not Marshmallow optimized. Also try going into settings and look for permissions, even if it's not M optimized, you can still change it there

Comment: @Robusto without a link to the app it's hard to say, but the app could a) not request any permissions or b) only request permissions Google says are "normal" and "undenyable" (such as Internet so they can make money via AdMob ;)

Comment: [Here is the app's home page](http://www.spanishdict.com/android). But it happens with other apps as well.

Comment: @Robusto Just checked the app permissions (I'm still on lollipop :P) and it requires no permissions.

Comment: @lolreppeatlol: Then shouldn't it say *that*?

Comment: No, not until you do something that makes it access something. For example, if I just installed Snapchat and started using the camera, Android would ask me "Allow Snapchat to access your Camera?" @Robusto

Comment: @Robusto There, it's edited ;)